# Elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3+p^2$, $p$ a prime, has torsion subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose that $p\ge 5$ is a prime and $P$ be a torsion point on the elliptic curve $E_5:y^2=x^3+p^2$. Using the Nagell-Lutz theorem we can write down all possible values of $y(P)$ (where $P=(x(P),y(P))$) and these are $\pm 1,\pm 3,\pm p,\pm 3p,\pm p^2,\pm 3p^2$. I want to show that $y(P)=\pm p$ is the only $y(P)$ value that "makes sense". I was able to dismiss all the others except for $y(P)=\pm 3$. In this case, we must have $x(P)^3=9-p^2$. I don't know where it can go wrong. Essentially it remains to prove that $p^2-9$ can never be a cube for primes $p\ge 5$. I am not sure how to show that. I have tried using several elementary number theory techniques but none of them seems to work. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $E_{tors}(\mathbb{Q})$ contains the points $(0, \pm p)$ of order $3$. Since $E_{tors}(\mathbb{Q})$ contains no $2$-torsion point $(x, 0)$, the only other possibility by Mazur's theorem is a point with $P = (x, \pm 3)$ with $3P = (0, \pm p)$. Writing out the latter equation for $x$ via the group law (and it should even be independent of $p$) is enough to eliminate that case.

Comment: This is a very nice argument. Thank you.